Unable to Upload macOS App with Zoom Video SDK to TestFlight – Asset Validation Errors
I’ve successfully integrated the Zoom Video SDK into my macOS application, and it is working as expected. However, I encountered issues while trying to share the app with my team via TestFlight. Here the Documentation Link :- https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/macos/integrate/
When I archive and upload the app to App Store Connect, I receive the following error related to the ssb_sdk framework:

Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle Identifier. The application bundle contains a tool or framework ssb_sdk [com.newdaythera.provider.pkg/Payload/NEW DAY THERAPEUTICS.app/Contents/Resources/ssb_sdk.bundle] using the bundle identifier ‘SaaSbee.ssb_sdk’, which is not a valid bundle identifier. (ID: d78befdf-f38b-403f-a7eb-52445225f757)

I’ve followed Zoom’s official documentation for SDK integration and used all the files provided, yet I cannot upload the build to TestFlight.
Additionally, I am encountering two other errors:

Asset validation failed
Bad CFBundleExecutable. Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in the nested bundle zConfCallbackDispatcher [com.newdaythera.provider.pkg/Payload/NEW DAY THERAPEUTICS.app/Contents/Frameworks/zConfCallbackDispatcher.framework] property list file. (ID: 1c0a09b8-b969-445a-8e75-68b4fed67016)


Asset validation failed
Bad Bundle Executable. You must include a valid CFBundleExecutable key in the nested bundle zConfCallbackDispatcher [com.newdaythera.provider.pkg/Payload/NEW DAY THERAPEUTICS.app/Contents/Frameworks/zConfCallbackDispatcher.framework] property list file. (ID: c942094f-bb45-4f99-81ab-cb2b562d6644)


